# Pass value javascript on laravel route

Tags: javascript, laravel, routes, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

i try to pass 'sat' value from route. My problem in this line.

```
 $return_array[] = array('value' => $v, 'id' =>$k, 'sat' => $k);
```

i can pass 'value' and 'id', but im confusing on 'sat', how to pass 'sat' field ?

```
'sat' => ??;
```

here is my route code

```
{
$term = Input::get('term');
$data = DB::table('sps')
            ->select(array('sps.namasp', 'kodesp', 'sat'))
            ->where('namasp','like','%'.$term.'%')
            ->lists('namasp','kodesp','sat');

$return_array = array();

foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
    if (strpos($v, $term) !== FALSE) {
        $return_array[] = array('value' => $v, 'id' =>$k, 'sat' => $k);
    }
}
return Response::json($return_array);
});
```

Comment: What is the question? [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: there is no problem at all passing "sat" variable to the view, its not reserved word or something

Comment: on my code i still using `'sat' => $k` , and the values will be same as "id" because im using `$k`, and i want replace `'sat' => $k` with right "sat" value

Comment: so do 'sat' => $theREALsat

Comment: how can i get $theREALsat bro ?

Comment: oh I think u need to do $v->sat

Comment: "sat" is field from "sps" table, see my code above,
use`$k->sat` still not work bro, im already try that

Comment: not work bro, `ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Trying to get property of non-object'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96119/discussion-between-amir-bar-and-dadan-hamdani).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem with your code is the lists() function take only 2 arguments
you can read more about it in the docs: [search for lists](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#retrieving-results)

this will work:

```
{
$term = Input::get('term');
$data = DB::table('sps')
            ->select(array('sps.namasp as namasp', 'kodesp', 'sat'))
            ->where('namasp','like','%'.$term.'%')
            ->get();

$return_array = array();

foreach ($data as $d) {
    if (strpos($d->namasp, $term) !== FALSE) {
        $return_array[] = array('value' => $d->namasp, 'id' =>$d->kodesp, 'sat' => $d->sat);
    }
}
return Response::json($return_array);
});
```